# AngularJS cookies not set

Tags: python, angularjs, cookies, flask, http-headers

I am developing an AngularJS website that uses an API backend on a different domain.

- The front-end website is hosted at: `www.example.com`
- The API is hosted at: `api.example.com`

I use Angular's `$http.post` to make an authentication request to the API which sets a cookie.  I then make a secondary `$http.get` call to the API and the cookie that was set from the `POST` request isn't being sent back to the server.  It looks like the cookie is getting lost somewhere.

The API is a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) Python app and I'm using flask-cors to enable cross-domain calls.  The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set to `http://www.example.com`  The domain on the cookie being set is `api.example.com`

I have setup the application to run under one domain using nginx and url rewriting.  So the front-end website is located at `www.example.com` and the API is accessed by `www.example.com/api/` and the cookies are being saved/used as expected.

I can't tell whether this is a problem with my front-end or API website configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are sending the http requests from another domain, you need to make sure that your `$http` is able to send cookies. In your app's config, add:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

This will allow AngularJS to send your browser's cookies to the server.

Comment: For those playing at home, this is what I included in my Flask app to ensure CORS worked nicely.  https://gist.github.com/brendanmckenzie/d50b32fbd25bc276dcf7